# remove geany old version

Tags: 14.04

I using Ubuntu 14.04LTE with gnome desktop. I've installed somehow Geany v1.26 sometime ago. Now, I wanted update to 1.31, so I did this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geany-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install geany geany-plugins
```

but I couldn't start new version. When I used search app for Geany it finds always the old version. I also tried to remove all by:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove geany
```

and again it removed the newest version, I could still find and run the old Geany version 1.26.

How to remove this? What else I can do to get rid off from my system? If execute the above remove command it says that there isn't any Geany package, but I still can find and run it.

Comment: It sounds like you installed the previous version outside of the package management system (from source, for example) - what does `type geany` say?

Comment: How did you install the old geany? If you did not install it from a repository, it will not work to remove it with apt-get. If you did, you can remove the ppa: `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:geany-dev/ppa` and try again with the command you tried before.

Comment: I don't remember how I did this before. `type geany` says (after translating)  path to geany is saved to (/usr/local/bin/geany)

Comment: it seems I didn't install from a repository because there is option to install it, but still I'm not able to run it after installing.

Comment: I found Geany folder with plugin folder in /usr/local/share I'm thinking if I can just hard remove these or I should execute some command to fully clean from system?

Comment: It will depends exactly how you installed it (whether from source, or from some kind of binary installer) - see [How to uninstall files installed from a source code or tarball?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928936/how-to-uninstall-files-installed-from-a-source-code-or-tarball). At a minimum, you might be able to get away with simply renaming `/usr/local/bin/geany` to `/usr/local/bin/geany.old` for example

Comment: Now I'm stacked  with geany error. I've deleted folders and files of the old geany and installed from repository but I can't run it. When I try to load it shows the error that can't open file /usr/local/share/geany/geany.glade, but after new installation there isn't any geany folder there. It seems that he is still looking for an old one. Now, I don't have an old one and can't run a new one.

Comment: Manually deleting files/directories without checking whether they belong to an installed package is always a bad idea. You probably need to re-install the `geany-common` package.

Comment: I've finally solved the problem. I found [website](http://linuxpitstop.com/install-geany-1-25-on-ubuntu-15-04/) for manual package compiling (only for 1.26 which I found on geany site) and after installing first, I then used sudo make uninstall which did the work (your link was helpful for that). So , finally I could install Geany from repository and it works! :) Thank you for trying to help.